# Error in overlay() function, calculation with raster and numeric values in R

Tags: r, loops, overlay, raster

I want to do some calculations with a list of rasters. Therefore I wrote a loop, which has so far worked fine when I only used rasters. Now I have calculations with  rasters and numeric vavlues and somehow this causes an error in the overlay function.
My code is:

## list files

```
NDVI <- list.files(path = 
"C:/Users/Felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/Daten/Datenverarbeitung_R/L8_NDVI",
               pattern = 'NDVI.tif$', full.names=T)
```

## define function

```
fun_PV <- function(x,y,z){((x-y)/(z+y))^2}
```

## Loop

```
for(i in seq_along(NDVI))
{

  PV <- overlay(x = raster(NDVI[i]),
                y = minValue(raster(NDVI[i])[[i]]),
                z = maxValue(raster(NDVI[i])[[i]]),
                fun = fun_PV)



  sat = substr(NDVI[i], 73, 77)
  path = substr(NDVI[i], 78, 84)
  date = substr(NDVI[i], 85, 92)




  setwd
  ("C:/Users/Felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/Daten/Datenverarbeitung_R/L8_PV")
  writeRaster(PV,filename = paste0(sat, path, date, '_PV', '.tif'))

  removeTmpFiles(h=0.1)
}
```

The error I get is:

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘overlay’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "numeric"’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask a question, always try to include some example data as I below.

Your arguments `y` and `z` in `overlay` are not Raster* objects. You only have one Raster* object at a time, so you do not need `overlay`. You can do something like:

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
NDVI <- c(f,f,f)
sat <- substr(NDVI, 73, 77)
path <- substr(NDVI, 78, 84)
date <- substr(NDVI, 85, 92)

fun_PV <- function(x,y,z){((x-y)/(z+y))^2}

setwd(".")

for(i in seq_along(NDVI)) {
    r <- raster(NDVI[i])
    PV <- fun_PV(r, minValue(r), maxValue(r))
#   writeRaster(PV, filename=paste0(sat[i], path[i], date[i], '_PV', '.tif'))
}
```